# Auto click on WebView

Tags: android, webview

How can I perform click on WebView from java code? Is it possible to click on a specified location (x,y)?

```
WebView.performClick()
```

doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by injecting javascript to your webview using loadUrl():

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:<your javascript here>");
```

This example code will perform a click on the element with id 'button_submit':

```
mWebView = new WebView(context);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:getElementById('button_submit').click();");
```

Comment: Can you please add some description please?

Comment: Hehe @Innocent - 8 years later?

Comment: Well @Innocent it's pretty straight-forward - loadUrl with `javascript:`  is the same as typing it i a regular browser. Try typing `javascript:alert('Hello world')` as url in your browser.

Comment: what is button_submit i don't have any button i just have a webview what should I do.

Comment: It's the button id inside the webview. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById